# Why does .html work and not innerHTML or appendChild

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I am trying to add an ajax response to a div (it's HTML code with tables, forms, etc).

In FF `innerHTML` works perfectly, but in IE it gives me an unknown error.

I tried lots of stuff, but I only got it working when I added jQuery and ran the `.html` method on the div I want the code inserted into.

Anyone care to explain why this works and not a simple `innerHTML`? I tried looking at the `.html()` code, but I guess I am not the great at JS because I didn't understand what it was doing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**IE** has *several* documented ([pre](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2008/03/bug-165-dynamic-pre-population-fails-in.html) | [table (thead, tbody, tr, tfoot)](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/12/bug-210-no-innerhtml-support-on-tables.html) | [div](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.ca/2007/10/bug-124-setting-innerhtml-problem-no1.html) |  [select](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/08/bug-274-dom-methods-on-select-lists.html)) **.innerHTML bugs**.

Thus libraries like [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/) abstract away those bugs for you by applying workarounds where needed for IE.

As for your specific error... without seeing the code it is hard to tell.

Setting the `.innerHTML` on pre's, *certain* div's, select's (if it does fail, will fail silently) but setting the `.innerHTML` on certain table elements (in certain versions of IE) will actually throw an error/exception.

*Note*: The issue with setting the `.innerHTML` of a div is very specific in condition and only occurs in IE6 & IE7.

Answer (score 0):

IE is fussy about changing `<table>s` from javascript.  I've run into trouble before if I don't specify the table down to the last detail, including the `<tbody>` tag.

Answer (score -1):

Just use jQuery and forget about all the horrible cross browser problems - you won't go back!

Answer (score -2):

I have same problem every day. Try with .innerText instad of .innerHTML, that will solve your problem. Answer is Javascript is parsed different in IE and FF.

Comment: Setting the .innerText won't work if the content truly is HTML. @AntonioCS is already using jQuery thus has solved the issue - he's just not sure exactly why IE is failing.