# Display variable content with html tags in EJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mongodb, ejs

I just started using a text editor on my page and I'm saving the data in mongoDB, 
so the data will contain html tags and It'll looks something like this `<b>test</b>`

I'm using basicaly bootstrap for my front-end, and I'd like to show the information of that variable in my html page.

if I display something like this:

**js:**

```
 event.information = '<b>test</b>'
```

**.html or .ejs:**

```
<p><%= event.information %></p>
```

**Current view:**

It's showing the data with the html tags e not the actual "effect" of the tag

```
<b>test</b>
```

**View (that I want):**

**test**

I just want to the page render my <%= event.information %> correctly and using the html tags to format the content and **not** display the html tags.

Comment: Please try to clarify what you mean. It's impossible to understand what exactly your problem here is...

Comment: requirement is not clear

Comment: details question please...

Comment: try `<:=event.information%>`

Comment: `<pre>your code</pre>`?

Comment: @putvande I already tried <pre> D:

Comment: @Dekel  is so hard to understand that i want to display my <%= event.information %> correctly and using the html tags to format the content and not display the html tags?

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/2522451/2968762

Comment: thanks everyone! @PranavCBalan you comment made me starts to realise my mistake haha

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
<p><%- event.information %></p>
```

instead of

```
<p><%= event.information %></p>
```

inside of your ejs file

<%- Outputs the unescaped value into the template.