# How to print an objects value that contains html with Javascript React

Tags: javascript, html, json, string, reactjs

So Currently I have this as my object for Props

```
{
    id: "1",
    summary: "HTML content inside this string",
    name: "John"
}
```

so what I was trying to do was remove the string so it would print the html as html not as a string but the error I would get with JSON.parse() is this SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

HTML content is a very simple Ul with a list of Li's.

How else can I render an objects value that holds HTML so it prints as HTML.

Any help would be amazing.

Thanks

Comment: The SynataxError you are getting more than likely means you are passing an object to JSON.parse() instead of JSON text, check the variable that you are using (console.log)

Comment: Removing the quote makes the string invalid. Instead use the string/text to create the required html element, refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522422/converting-a-javascript-string-to-a-html-object

Answer (score 0):

Removing the quote makes the string invalid. Instead use the string/text to create the required html element.

Check below example.

```js
var props = {
  id: "1",
  summary: "<div><ul><li>Some text here</li></ul></div>",
  name: "John"
}

var htmlObject = document.createElement('div');
htmlObject.innerHTML = props.summary;
document.getElementById("t").appendChild(htmlObject);
```

```html
<div id="t">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out and Thank you for all your help.

What I did to get it to render with react was create a function for the output to be modified

```
summary() {
    return {__html: modal.summary
}
```

Then I used the dangerouslySetInnerHTML and it worked

```
<div id="summary" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={summary()} />
```