# How can I store HTML markup in JSON?

Tags: javascript, html, json, twitter-bootstrap

I have a data stored in a json variable to list the categories and their subcategory if any. How can I write HTML code / HTML table in a json variable as I do for the data to display category name, description and so on in cells of a HTML table?

I want for example a table with 3 columns where I can write data (the key "text" of the json variable) in each of these columns. Even if writing the table for just one column would be useful to use a bootstrap data table to limit the entries per page.

```
var jsonVar = [{
  text: "Name: {{ category.name }}",
  icon: "fa fa-home fa-fw",
  nodes: [{
    text: "subcategory: {{ category.subcategory.name }}",
    icon: "fa fa-tree fa-fw",
    nodes: [{
      icon: "fa fa-user fa-fw",
      text: "Created By: {{ subactegory.createdBy}}"
    }]
  }]
}];
```

Thanks in advance for your comments.

Example:

Comment: You shouldn't be putting markup in json. That would be like storing an entire car in a gas can.  Use json data to render markup using other code.

Comment: FYI, your mention of the loop was an unnecessary distraction here. It's completely irrelevant how you construct your data. Whatever that was wasn't JavaScript anyway.

Comment: If you _do_ actually want to store markup in your data, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/2522422/1264804.

Comment: FYI again... this isn't really JSON anyway (unless you're transporting it as a string). It's just a JavaScript array.

Comment: @isherwood this is the tree json data from the bootstrap treeview. Except from having static data in the json variable, my data are coming from the database, as I said my loop works perfectly. I just want to create a bootstrap data table in the variable so that I can take advantage of the search and limit the number of entries per page.