# el.classList is undefined

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events

I'm trying to add a class to a div in pure JS once a link is clicked (In this case, the link has id `#switchlogin`). When I console.log my element, I am able to click through the object and see that it currently has two names in its `classList`. However, when I `console.log element.classList`, I receive an "undefined". I am unsure why I'm receiving undefined, and why I cannot add my new class name.

The issue is recreated here: https://jsfiddle.net/swf5zc74/

Here is a portion of my HTML:

```
   <div class="sign_in modal">

      <h1>Get Started!</h1>

      <form action="" method="get">

        <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Name" required>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit">

      </form>

      <h3><a href="#" id="switchLogin">Been Here Before?</a></h3>
    </div>
```

My JS:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body'),
    signIn = document.getElementsByClassName('sign_in modal'),
    logIn = document.getElementsByClassName('log_in'),
    switchLogIn = document.getElementById('switchLogin'),
    switchSignIn = document.getElementById('switchSignin'),
    link = document.querySelector('a');

link.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    if ((e.target || e.srcElement).id == 'switchLogin'){
        console.log(signIn);
        console.log(signIn.classList);
        signIn.classList += ' slideOut';
    }else{
        console.log("nope");
    }
})
```

Comment: If you're using `addEventListener()`, there's no reason for `(e.target || e.srcElement)`. Just use `e.target`.

Comment: Okay, awesome. I used e.srcElement because I read IE doesn't support e.target. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Does this answer your question? [document.getElementsByClassName().innerHTML always returns "undefined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17896746/document-getelementsbyclassname-innerhtml-always-returns-undefined)

Comment: Not OP's problem, but I've wound up at this thread [trying to access `.classList` on a `element.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71474999/6243352) which is undefined. Beware!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`signIn` is the result of `document.getElementsByClassName('sign_in modal')` - `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection - so you have to reference the index you want:

```
console.log(signIn[0].classList);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/swf5zc74/1/

Comment: Oh okay. But now when I try to add my new class using .push, I receive an error that says it's not a function

` var classes = signIn[0].classList;     classes.push("slideOut");`

Results in `Uncaught TypeError: classes.push is not a function(…)`
?

Comment: @AngelinaBethoney Read more on classList here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Answer (score 4):

document.getElementsByClassName returns an "array-like" collection of elements, even if there is only one element with that class name.  To access elements with document.getElementsByClassName, you can use array syntax.

for exampe logIn = document.getElementsByClassName('log_in')[0]

want to add a class to that element?

`document.getElementsByClassName('log_in')[0].className += " foo";`