# mootools: Creating a new DOM element from an HTML

Tags: javascript, mootools

How to create DOM elements from string (pass from ajax) in Mootools?

In jQuery a simple solution is `$( elements )`

```
var elements = '<i>This is italic</i><b>this bold</b>...';
```

Comment: http://mootools.net/blog/2010/03/19/a-better-way-to-use-elements/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a string, you would use the Element class:

```
var el = new Element('div#id.class', {
    text: 'My text',
});
```

With a string, you can check how it's one in Request.HTML, [see here](https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/3eb050d68dc2403b39d3c1b15e925735ff1eacbb/Source/Request/Request.HTML.js#L40).

```
var temp = new Element('div').set('html', response.html);
response.tree = temp.childNodes;
response.elements = temp.getElements(options.filter || '*');
```

Basically Mootools elements & DOM elements are the same, this is another SO questions which creates DOM nodes from HTML: [Creating a new DOM element from an HTML string using built-in DOM methods or prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143/creating-a-new-dom-element-from-an-html-string-using-built-in-dom-methods-or-pro)

From old Mootools forums, I found an [interesting idea](http://mootools-users.660466.n2.nabble.com/Moo-New-element-from-html-string-td3557543.html) too: add a new method Element.fromString() or String.toElement() which would contain this logic.

Answer (score 6):

Simple as: `Elements.from('<i>This is italic</i><b>this bold</b>')`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the latest *Mootools 1.6.0*.
It throws `Elements.from` is not a function.

This one works for me:

```
var html = '<img src='+item.src+'>';
var el = new Element('li').set('html', html);
```

The working code: http://jsfiddle.net/chetabahana/qbx9b5pm/