# Javascript regex replace: invalid quantifier

Tags: javascript, regex

I can't make this regex work in javascript:

```
pat = new RegExp("Lorem(?=([^<]*($|<a|<[^/]|</[^a]))*($|(?<=a)))", "g");
test = test.replace(pat, '<a href="#">Lorem</a>');
```

I get the error: `invalid quantifier`.

But here is working: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2va0g

Thanks for your help :)

### EDIT

I need to replace every occurrence of "String" with a link, but only if "String" wasn't already a link.

Es.

```html
This is a <a href="#">String</a>. This is another String.
```

=>

```html
This is a <a href="#">String</a>. This is another <a href="#">String</a>.
```

Better if can check also the url of the link es:

```html
This is a <a href="http://www.test.com/String">link</a>
```

=>

```html
This is a <a href="http://www.test.com/String">link</a>
```

Probably is enough to replace all String that are not inside `<a ... </a>` (the first a TAG is not closed on purpose)

Comment: `?<=` lookbehinds are not supported in JS.

Comment: That's a pity, well thanks for your help, i'll have to find another solution.

Comment: Well, if you update the question to explain what's the exact expected behavior of your regex, someone may be able to help adapting it.

Comment: This is JavaScript, *the* language for dom manipulations. And yet you're STILL use regex to parse HTML. WHY?!

Comment: Because the text that I want to replace is in a textarea, precisely is the content of a tinyMCE that I get with: parent.tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent()

Comment: [Don't use Regex to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1048572). This is also true for manipulation. As you seem to be in a browser environment, it really shouldn't be hard to use the DOM

Comment: So then parse it, getting back DOM nodes that you can inspect and operate on. Even if you never append them to the page, you can still treat them like DOM nodes.

Comment: @user1763784: So? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143/creating-a-new-dom-element-from-an-html-string-using-built-in-dom-methods-or-pro

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - In defense of the OP (note, I'm not a regex fan, that high-brow gobbledygook), you really haven't shown *how* to accomplish the same effect with DOM methods either. All you've done is point out it's an option, but how would that look?

Comment: Well, I can operate on them as DOM nodes, but at the end of the day I still have to replace the String with the link :/ I can't see the advantage of that method, maybe an example could help.

Comment: Welcome to SO, btw. The back-and-forth is normal. Don't be discouraged.

Comment: @user1763784: Replacing a string for the link isn't the problem. The problem is finding the string, making sure it's not a tag name, or an attribute name, or an attribute value. Or part of a link, or one of the other million causes why you may not want it to occur.

Comment: I've solved using this: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/find-and-replace-text-with-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

See this example [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/atiruz/kuhAK/1/)

```
var toreplace = "String"; // Text to find
var rx = new RegExp ("((?!\/)" + toreplace + "(?!\"))(?!<(.*?)>)", "g");
var txt = "This is a <a href=\"#\">String</a>. This is another String."; // Text to replace.
var newtxt = txt.replace (rx, '<a href="#">$1</a>'); // New Text
```

The result is:

```html
This is a <a href="#">String</a>. This is another String.
```

=>

```html
This is a <a href="#">String</a>. This is another <a href="#">String</a>.
```