# 'String contains an invalid character' when using document.createElement()

Tags: javascript

```
var NewRow = document.createElement("<tr><td align='left' valign='top'  width='9%;'  ><img width='32px' height='32px' src='images/" + ProfilePic + "'  /></td><td align='left' valign='Top' ><span class='MsgSpan'>" + Msg + "</span></td><td align='right' align='left' valign='top' style='color:Gray;' >" + Date + "</td></tr>");
```

I am getting an error:

```
InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The string you pass to `document.createElement` is the type of the element, e.g. `tr`.

If you really want to assemble your HTML as a big string, I suppose you could write:

```
var newRow = document.createElement('tr');
newRow.innerHTML = "<td align='left' valign='top'  width='9%;'  ><img width='32px' height='32px' src='images/" + ProfilePic + "'  /></td><td align='left' valign='Top' ><span class='MsgSpan'>" + Msg + "</span></td><td align='right' align='left' valign='top' style='color:Gray;' >" + Date + "</td>";
```

but it's probably cleaner/faster/safer to use DOM manipulation for the whole thing.

Comment: `NewRow` should be `newRow` on the first line.

Answer (score 4):

### Check extra space after class name

In my case I had an extra space when adding a css class to a div.

I had this

```
menuLinksDiv.classList.remove('show-element ');
```

Removed the space after `show-element` string and no error

```
menuLinksDiv.classList.remove('show-element');
```

Answer (score 2):

I have one similar answer below:
Here, I have defined the elements in HTML and not created them separately, so that it will be easy to change and debug.

```
var ProfilePic = "abl.jpg";
var Msg="Hi";
var Date = "June 10, 2010";
function doit() {
   var NewRow ="<tr><td align='left' valign='top'  width='9px'  ><img width='32px' height='32px' src='images/" + ProfilePic + "'  /></td><td align='left' valign='Top' ><span class='MsgSpan'>" + Msg + "</span></td><td align='right' align='left' valign='top' style='color:Gray;' >" + Date + "</td></tr>";
   var element = document.getElementById("tbl_body");
   element.innerHTML +=NewRow;
}
```

The problem with the previous code was `createElement` where you have to create row, then `td` then text and then append.

Comment: Are you suggesting (s)he change `style='color:Gray;'` to `style='color:Gray'`? Trust me, that won't make a difference; those notations are 100% equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

Check this out:

[Creating a new DOM element from an HTML string using built-in DOM methods or Prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143/creating-a-new-dom-element-from-an-html-string-using-built-in-dom-methods-or-pro)

You can not pass HTML string to createElement method, instead use innerHTML property as shown in the above link.