# How to create dynamic HTML?

Tags: javascript

with out a library, given an anchor element.

so `render(anchor_element)` will render content in the browser.

I'm asking about the best approach.  My idea was to use `HTMLToElement` and from there apply CSS to it which has already been loaded.

```
$P.HTMLToElement = function (html) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = html;
    return div.firstChild;
};
```

Comment: what than with this `div` element? What's the practical use for that script?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143/creating-a-new-dom-element-from-an-html-string-using-built-in-dom-methods-or-pro ... got the idea from here.

Comment: What if html contains multiple siblings at the same top level e.g. `<p>text</p><span>text2</span>` ?

Comment: actually I can just use that method, as I'm working with one root node...the CSS will be in the HTML ... no need to "apply it"

Comment: Is using jQuery an option? I so, you can simple do something like `$(html).get()`

Comment: this seems like a good way in general to not have redundant HTML, write the string once and than create as many copies as you need using HTMLToElement