# How can I get the id within a span represented as a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
var span = '<span class="we w_o_r_d_s" id="we" contenteditable="false">we</span>' 

console.log(span.id);
console.log(span.attr('id'));
console.log(span.getAttribute('id'));

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = span;


console.log(div.id);
console.log(div.attr('id'));
console.log(div.getAttribute('id'));



//I want to log `we`
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3BTdk/1/

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143/creating-a-new-dom-element-from-an-html-string-using-built-in-dom-methods-or-pro) but couldn't get it.  THanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a jQuery object and use `.attr('id')` to get the id.

```
var span = '<span class="we w_o_r_d_s" id="we" contenteditable="false">we</span>'; 
var id = $(span).attr('id');
```

**[The demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/3BTdk/4/)**

Without jQuery version:

```
var tmp = document.createElement('p'); 
tmp.innerHTML=span;
console.log(tmp.childNodes[0].id);
```

**[And the demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/3BTdk/5/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jQuery` function to convert the string to jQuery object. It will allow you to apply `jQuery` `selectors / functions` on it.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/3BTdk/2/)**

```
var span = jQuery ('<span class="we w_o_r_d_s" id="we" contenteditable="false">we</span>');
var id = span.attr('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

if page has just one span

then `var id = $('span').attr('id');`

http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/3BTdk/3/

Answer (score 1):

instead of `span.attr('id')` use `$(span).attr('id')`

The reason you might want to wrap `jQuery/$` functionality around a DOM element should be
obvious. Doing so gives you the ability to use jQuery chaining, should you have need for it.

Answer (score 0):

See your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3BTdk/7/) which I updated...

Or use this:

```
console.log($(span).attr('id'));
```