# Using Html.dropdownList() in Javascript Code

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, html.dropdownlistfor

I want to add row to my table dynamicly like this :

```
 var tableRef = document.getElementById('tblData').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
        var newRow = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);
        var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
        newCell.appendChild(document.createElement('input'));
        var newCell = newRow.insertCell(1);
        newCell.appendChild('@Html.DropDownList("AppVersionGroupId", string.Empty)');
```

but output is :

```
newCell.appendChild('<select id="AppVersionGroupId" name="AppVersionGroupId"><option value=""></option>
<option value="46a08053-56e3-4320-aec3-7b521cca28ab">op1</option>
<option value="36ff6b7a-bdef-4506-b771-95cc42cd2667">op2</option>
<option value="e84fcfc5-8a46-47fd-8584-c00a5642f246">op3</option>
</select>');
```

how can I use html.!!! in my javascript ?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks a lot guys . The answer that work for me was :

```
newCell.innerHTML = '@Ajax.JavaScriptStringEncode(Html.DropDownList("AppVersionGroupId", string.Empty).ToHtmlString())'
```

If anything is wrong let me know .

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@Html.Raw` and the `innerHtml` JavaScript function:

```
newCell.innerHtml = '@Html.Raw(Html.DropDownList("AppVersionGroupId", string.Empty)');
```

Comment: It dos not work : 
        var newCell = newRow.insertCell(1);
        newCell.appendChild('<select id="AppVersionGroupId" name="AppVersionGroupId"><option value=""></option>
<option value="46a08053-56e3-4320-aec3-7b521cca28ab">op1</option>
<option value="36ff6b7a-bdef-4506-b771-95cc42cd2667">op2</option>
<option value="e84fcfc5-8a46-47fd-8584-c00a5642f246">op3</option>
</select>');

Comment: why output create in multiline ?!

Comment: @JavadAzimi, yup, my bad. `innerHtml` is not a function, but a property. I updated the answer.

Comment: thanks bro... problem : output break in multiline and made error

Comment: newCell2.innerHTML = '<select id="AppVersionGroupId" name="AppVersionGroupId"><option value=""></option>
<option value="46a08053-56e3-4320-aec3-7b521cca28ab">باگ</option>...

Answer (score 0):

`appendChild` expect a `DOM node` and not `String`, so what you need is a function that create DOM element from a given HTML string

```
function createElementFromHtml(html){ 
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = html;
  return div.childNodes;
};
```

after defining the above function in your main script, you can call it like this

```
var dropDown = createElementFromHtml('@Html.DropDownList("AppVersionGroupId", string.Empty)');
newCell.appendChild(dropDown); // <--- here DOMElement and not string
```

Hope this help!

References:

- [Creating a new DOM element from an HTML string using built-in DOM methods or prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143/creating-a-new-dom-element-from-an-html-string-using-built-in-dom-methods-or-pro)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild

Comment: thanks a lot .. it work like @Andrei V solution . But problem is dropDown tags are in multiline and breaked . it should be in single line and between two "'"