# Passing Razor syntax to a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

This is the declaration I am trying to place within a variable

```
var levelDropdown = "@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Level, Model.Levels, null, null)";
var level = "<div class='col-sm-3 search-spacing'><label for='Level'>Level</label>" + levelDropdown +"</select></div>";
```

However, when I run it, I get an invalid identifier error. When I remove these 2 lines, the page loads again. Is there a way to place razor syntax into a javascript variable or how can I convert this to normal html syntax instead?

Comment: You have additional `</select>` closing tag which should be removed. Also using `DropDownListFor` assignment for JS variable is not considered a good way, why not just render it on CSHTML page directly?

Comment: I'll try to render them on cshtml first then. I didn't think to do that earlier.

Comment: Check the view source of the page and you will understand what is breaking (multi line without proper closing bracket)

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of `DropDownListFor` for `levelDropdown` is not work because it creates line breaks between `<select>` and `<option>` tags, as shown in result below:

```js
var levelDropdown = "<select id="Level" name="Level"><option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
<option value="3">Option 3</option>
<option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>";
```

The code above is not a valid JS, hence `Unexpected identifier` error occurred.

To fix this problem, use `Ajax.JavaScriptStringEncode()` method together with `ToHtmlString()` to generate correct HTML:

```js
var levelDropdown = '@Ajax.JavaScriptStringEncode(Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Level, Model.Levels, null, null).ToHtmlString())';
```

Then strip out all line breaks inside `levelDropdown` by using `String.replace()` on JS:

```js
var level = "<div class='col-sm-3 search-spacing'><label for='Level'>Level</label>" + 
             levelDropdown.replace(/(\r\n\t|\n|\r\t)/gm,"") +"</div>";
```

Finally use `append()` to add the dropdown into target element:

```js
$('#targetElement').append(level);
```

**Note:** The solution above only applies for MVC 5 (see [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/D1SH2P)). If Core MVC is used, there's no [`Ajax.JavaScriptStringEncode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.ajaxhelper.javascriptstringencode?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) and `ToHtmlString()` methods for string conversion against `DropDownListFor`, hence create your own `ToHtmlString()` method with helper class and [`System.Text.Encodings.Web.JavaScriptEncoder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encodings.web.javascriptencoder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-2.1) to encode the output:

**Helper class**

```csharp
public static string ToHtmlString(this IHtmlContent htmlContent)
{
    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    {
        htmlContent.WriteTo(writer, System.Text.Encodings.Web.HtmlEncoder.Default);
        return writer.ToString();
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@{
    // include the helper class 
    var ddlf = System.Text.Encodings.Web.JavaScriptEncoder.Default.Encode(Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Level, Model.Levels, null, null).ToHtmlString());
}
```

```js
<script>
    var levelDropdown = '@ddlf';
    var level = "<div class='col-sm-3 search-spacing'><label for='Level'>Level</label>" + 
                levelDropdown.replace(/(\r\n\t|\n|\r\t)/gm,"") +"</div>";
    $('#targetElement').append(level);
</script>
```

Related issue:

[Using Html.dropdownList() in Javascript Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23333344/using-html-dropdownlist-in-javascript-code)