# JavaScript RegExp Lookbehind Alternative?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I made a regular expression that matches for `title="..."` in `<a>`; unfortunately, it also matches for `title="..."` in `<img/>`.

Is there a way to tell the regular expression to **ONLY** look for `title="..."` in `<a>`?  I can't use a look-behind method like `(?<=<a\s+)` because they're **NOT** supported in JavaScript.

**Here's my expression:**

```
/((title=".+")(?=\s*href))|(title=".+")/igm;
```

**The above expression matches the following:**

[image]

As you can see, it matches for `title="..."` found in `<img/>`; I need the expression to exclude titles found in image tags.

**[Here](http://regexr.com/392ug) is the link to the RegExp.**

---

Also, if possible, I need to get rid of the title=" " around the title.  So, only return `title AFTER href` and `title BEFORE href`.  If not possible, I guess I can use `.replace()` and replace it with `""`.

---

zx81's expression:

[image]

Comment: Every time I see someone use regular expressions to match strings in a non-regular language I die a little inside.

Comment: @AaditMShah - This is in a textarea, it's not in the DOM as HTML elements on a webpage.  Therefore, that principle doesn't apply, right?  The user types in the HTML, so basically, it's just text with greater and less than signs that appear to be HTML

Comment: @Matthew It's possible to convert a string into DOM objects, though. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143/creating-a-new-dom-element-from-an-html-string-using-built-in-dom-methods-or-pro

Comment: If the user enters the HTML in a textarea, then.. *valid HTML* is single quotes, double quotes and *no quotes* (for attributes/properties without spaces). The order of title vs href (or other attributes/properties like id, class, name, alt, etc.) usually also doesn't matter.. (Something to be aware of if and when to instruct your users to use a specific formatting/order so your app considers it valid html or performs the intended operation). So.. user entering html is actually the worst possible scenario to regex!

Comment: @GitaarLAB I'm making a HTML to markdown convertor

Comment: That's going to eat a big chunk of your life (without better solutions/library's). With the best possible intentions (knowing what you are trying to do): might I suggest to google a little further on proper html-parsing libraries? I can't suggest one off the top of my head, sorry, but I am absolutely positive there are some solid working libraries and solutions.

Comment: Whether you write HTML in a textarea or display it as a page, HTML is still not a regular language. You can't parse non-regular languages using regular expressions. You need a full-blown HTML parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you can do this with a single regular expression in JavaScript; however, you could do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/KYfKT/1/

```
var str = '\
<a href="www.google.com" title="some title">\
<a href="www.google.com" title="some other title">\
<a href="www.google.com">\
<img href="www.google.com" title="some title">\
';

var matches = [];
//-- somewhat hacky use of .replace() in order to utilize the callback on each <a> tag
str.replace(/\<a[^\>]+\>/g, function (match) {
    //-- if the <a> tag includes a title, push it onto matches
    var title = match.match(/((title=".+")(?=\s*href))|(title=".+")/igm);
    title && matches.push(title[0].substr(7, title[0].length - 8));
});

document.body.innerText = JSON.stringify(matches);
```

---

You should probably utilize the DOM for this, rather than regular expressions:

http://jsfiddle.net/KYfKT/3/

```
var str = '\
<a href="www.google.com" title="some title">Some Text</a>\
<a href="www.google.com" title="some other title">Some Text</a>\
<a href="www.google.com">Some Text</a>\
<img href="www.google.com" title="some title"/>\
';

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = str;
var titles = Array.apply(this, div.querySelectorAll('a[title]')).map(function (item) { return item.title; });

document.body.innerText = titles;
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you must know that most people prefer to parse html with a DOM parser, as regex can present certain hazards. That being said, for this straightforward task (no nesting), here is what you can do in regex.

**Use Capture Groups**

We don't have lookbehinds or `\K` in JavaScript, but we can capture what we like to a capture group, then retrieve the match from that group, ignoring the rest.

This regex captures the title to Group 1:

```
<a [^>]*?(title="[^"]*")
```

On [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/aL5dV5/2), look at the Group 1 captures in the right pane: that's what we are interested in.

**Sample JavaScript Code**

```
var unique_results = []; 
var yourString = 'your_test_string'
var myregex = /<a [^>]*?(title="[^"]*")/g;
var thematch = myregex.exec(yourString);
while (thematch != null) {
    // is it unique?
    if(unique_results.indexOf(thematch[1]) <0) {
        // add it to array of unique results
        unique_results.push(thematch[1]);
        document.write(thematch[1],"<br />");    
    }
    // match the next one
    thematch = myregex.exec(yourString);
}
```

**Explanation**

- `<a` matches the beginning of the tag
- `[^>]*?` lazily matches any chars that are not a `>`, up to...
- `(` capture group
- `title="` literal chars
- `[^"]*` any chars that are not a quote
- `"` closing quote
- `)` end Group 1

Comment: Added explanation... Let me know if you have questions or need any tweaks. :)

Comment: Thank you for helping me out!  I updated my question w/ a screenshot of the regular expression you gave me, and it doesn't seem to work correctly?  Am I implementing it wrong?

Comment: `Am I implementing it wrong?` I'm assuming you want to implement it in code, right? This screenshot just shows the entire match. But we're only interested in Group 1, which the code returns. This is a technique for JS as it doesn't have lookarounds. On [this demo](http://regex101.com/r/aL5dV5/1), you can see the change of color for Group 1, and see the titles in the pane on the right. That's what the code will give you. :)

Comment: What about [this](http://regex101.com/r/aL5dV5/3) demo?  It only returns one match.  How about when the title comes before?

Comment: In regex101 you need to add the `g` flag to allow multiple matches: [see this demo](http://regex101.com/r/aL5dV5/4) ` How about when the title comes before?` What do you mean? Not understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where your html-sources come from, but I do know some browsers do not respect the casing (or attribute-order) of source when fetched as 'innerHTML'.

Also, both authors *and* browsers can use single and double quotes.
These are the most common 2 cross-browser pitfalls that I know of.

Thus, you could try: `/<a [^>]*?title=(['"])([^\1]*?)\1/gi`

It performs a non-greedy case-insensitive search using [back-references](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#grouping-back-references) to solve the case of single vs double quotes.

The first part is already explained by zx81's answer. `\1` matches the first capturing group, thus it matches the used opening quote. Now the second capturing group should contain the bare title-string.

A simple example:

```
var rxp=/<a [^>]*?title=(['"])([^\1]*?)\1/gi
,   res=[]
,   tmp
;

while( tmp=rxp.exec(str) ){  // str is your string
  res.push( tmp[2] );        //example of adding the strings to an array.
}
```

However as pointed out by others, it really is bad (in general) to regex tag-soup (aka HTML). Robert Messerle's alternative (using the DOM) is preferable!

**Warning** (I almost forgot)..
IE6 (and others?) has this nice 'memory-saving feature' to conveniently delete all unneeded quotes (for strings that don't need spaces). So, there, this regex (and zx81's) would **fail**, since they rely on the use of quotes!!!! Back to the drawing-board.. (a seemingly never-ending process when regexing HTML).