# set "required" to text_field by rails view to validation on client side

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, required

In my rails partial (_form.html.erb) I wrote this:

```
<%= f.text_field :title, required: true %>
```

The generated html is:

```
<input required="required" type="text" name="task[title]" id="task_title">
```

It works fine, but I want this:

```
<input type="text" name="task[title]" id="task_title" required>
```

How to set just 'required' into tag?

Comment: can u try to put this required: 'required' in tag?

Comment: yeap, but the result is the same

Comment: Long story short, you can not do this using helper methods. If you need this, you have to do some work around. But why do you want to do this, is this really needed? And worthy of doing?

Comment: no, this is not really needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840083/how-to-generate-dom-nodes-with-valueless-attributes) post. There is no such thing as a valueless attribute.

So, no matter what you write `required` or `required='true'` or `required='false'`, would all mean the same thing. The input is required.