# jQuery - get HTML from an HTML string

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to get HTML from a HTML string, I am trying to do this:

```
var html = '<ul><li>list 1</li><li>List</li></ul>';
console.log($(html).find('ul').html());
```

But, this return `undefined`.

**What I am trying to do in above code:**

actually my html string is returned by an ajax request. And I want to append this html string to a `<ul>`. so before appending HTML string I want to remove `<ul>` tags returned from ajax.

Please help me get string without `<ul>`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143/creating-a-new-dom-element-from-an-html-string-using-built-in-dom-methods-or-pro might help `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(html)` is itself an object of `ul` node. You don't need to find it. You can simply use `.html()` for created object:

```
$(html).html();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/manantwar/2ay7xk6s/)**

Answer (score 2):

The `ul` is the root node, so you are effectively searching for `ul` within the `ul`, which is finding nothing. Instead, use `filter()` as this will include the root:

```
var html = '<ul><li>list 1</li><li>List</li></ul>';
console.log($(html).filter('ul').html());
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/h9s0y6y8/)

Answer (score 1):

Just

```
var html = "<ul><li>list 1</li><li>List</li></ul>";
console.log($(html).html());
```

Answer (score 1):

you could replace pieces of string where it matches with sub-string you want:

```
// set string you'd replace
var html = '<ul><li>list 1</li><li>List</li></ul>';
// replace first tag with empty string
var part_res = html.replace("<ul>", "");
// replace last tag with empty string
var res = part_res.replace("</ul>", "");
// print out the new result
console.log(res);
```