# How do I create an element from html formatted text?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, canvas

I'm using Angular 1.29 and Chrome.

I have some text like

```
<p>Text <strong> bold </strong> </p>
```

And I need to turn it into an `element`, because the library that I'm using, [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas), needs to be sent one.

So I've tried this, which I took from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143/creating-a-new-dom-element-from-an-html-string-using-built-in-dom-methods-or-pro)

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = $scope.presData.text;
var element = div.firstChild;
    html2canvas(element,{
        onrendered:function(newCanvas){
            document.getElementById("newPresentation").appendChild(newCanvas);
        }
    });
```

Where my text is in `$scope.presData.text`, 
But that didn't work. This creates a canvas with a width and height of 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using innerHTML of an HTML element should format them as document nodes.

```
var HTMLString = '<p>Text <strong> bold </strong> </p>';
var HTMLStringContainer = document.createElement('div');
HTMLStringContainer.innerHTML = HTMLString;
```

If you're having some issues with your canvas, I think your issue lies elsewhere.

Comment: wouldn't this output the original string wrapped in a div rather than the original string simply as an element?

Comment: @Jrulle Calling HTMLStringrontainer will return a div with valid <p> and <strong> HTML elements nested within. You can then query the children of the container to get the element directly. OP's code should be working, at least the element creation portion.

Comment: Using the updated version, this also creates a canvas with a width and height of 0. Maybe my issue is elsewhere, as you say.

Comment: Yeah, try querying the element with a console.log() call before calling the html2canvas function. It should confirm that you have a valid HTML element.

Comment: @Aweary Is the element I want to send it `HTMLStringContainer`, or `HTMLStringContainer.innerHTML`?

Comment: After setting `innerHTML` you'd just call HTMLStringContainer in this example. That would give you the `<div> <p> <strong>` element stack. If you wanted just the `<p>` and `<strong>` elements, you'd call `HTMLStringContainer.firstChild`

Comment: console.logging `HTMLStringContainer` gives me the element stack.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to set up your strings as html nodes... it is robust and will handle alot of different situation (multiple sibling nodes at the highest level for example). **[jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pqy92pkj/)**

```
// HTML string
var s = '<p>Text <strong> bold </strong> </p>';

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = s;
var elements = div.childNodes;

//using your above canvas code
var element = elements[0];
html2canvas(element,{
    onrendered:function(newCanvas){
        document.getElementById("newPresentation").appendChild(newCanvas);
    }
});

//multiple elements
//for(var i=0; i < elements.length; i++){
    //html2canvas(elements[i],{
          //onrendered:function(newCanvas){
                //document.getElementById("newPresentation").appendChild(newCanvas);
          //}
      //});
//}
```

Comment: This also creates a canvas with a width and height of 0.