# How to use $sce.trustAsHtml with some HTML node

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I face the problem that I get some string from the server that represents an html
and I need to parse style attrs for some nodes and then show this html inside the view with Angular.

So I see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/494348/1022726 that helps me to create
an html node from a string then I go over each item and change styles.
In the end I do $sce.trustAsHtml with the value of innerHTML.

I have this code http://plnkr.co/edit/HUfAGR2uNMwb48rqXbkk?p=preview

```
<div ng-bind-html="trustedHtml"></div>

function($scope, $sce) {
  var s = '<h1 style="color: red; font-size: 16px;">Subheader</h1><p style="font-size: 12px;">text</p>';
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = s;

  $(div).find("*").each(function () {
    $(this).height('100px');
  });

  $scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(div.innerHTML);
}]);
```

I want to know if there are any better ways to parse a string that represents html and then show that html in the view.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You could make it into a filter, such as

```
app.filter('trusted', function($sce){
  return function(text) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
  };
});
```

and then in your html you could have

```
<div ng-bind-html="text | trusted"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for you reply. Do you know if this is a legit usage $sce.trustAsHtml(div.innerHTML) of trustAsHtml method?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be. Someone correct me if I'm mistaken.