# Retrieving html tag values with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to try retrieve "Charlotte" from this piece of HTML code, using regex:

```
<a href="/anime/28999/Charlotte" target="_blank" class="animetitle" title="Anime Information">
    <span>Charlotte</span>
</a>
```

The issue is, I need to get the name "Charlotte" out from the class each and every time, for different titles. Whether this be from the href attribute or the span tags.

I've tried:

```
<span(?:[^>]+class=\"(.*?)\"[^>]*)?>(.*?)<\/span>
```

However this only works for the first result it finds. I cannot use a parser at this stage, so any help on this if possible will be very appreciated.

Side note - I'm trying to use this regex under JavaScript.

EDIT: The html is being retrieved through XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Why not get the href attribute using javascript and perform regex on that instead?

Comment: Trying to get Charlotte from href attribute or from the span??

Comment: As long as I can get the keyword Charlotte out, it'll work

Comment: As said in OP, there may be multiple lines with different titles other than Charlotte, which is why I need to get information by class/tags

Answer (score 0):

## edit

Because of your comment:

> Cannot use jquery, I'm using XMLHttpRequest

The point of the answer wasn't to recommend a specific library. The intent is to show that it's best to natively traverse the DOM rather than attempting to "parse" HTML with regular expressions, which usually doesn't work out well in the end (see [this famous answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2714730)).

I assume you're getting that HTML as your XHR response. So, you can simply create a DOM node, traverse that, and pull the text out (see [this answer for an explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/494348/2714730)):

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = response; // the response of your XHR
```

Then just traverse the DOM node you've created:

```
div.getElementsByClassName('.animetitle')[0].textContent; // Charlotte
```

## original answer

```
var href = $('.animetitle').attr('href');
var name = href.split('/').pop(); // => Charlotte
```

Comment: Note: You would need jQuery for this solution.

Comment: Also, it takes the href, and i think from the original post, he meant the text in the contained span.

Comment: Cannot use jquery, I'm using XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not actually answering your question, i'm suggesting a different approach.

Try selecting the element with JavaScript, and then read the attribute itself. It is both safer and faster. And it's also probably more robust against future changes.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('animetitle');
var element = elements[0]; // this would probably be in a loop
element.textContent // <-- this is what you want
```

Comment: It would be nice if the downvoter could explain why he/she downvoted?
(the "not answering" means: i don't give you a *regex* even though you asked for one. Still: i think this is the best solution to your problem.)

Comment: Upvoted, at least you're being helpful. I updated my OP, I'm not sure this will work for XMLHttpRequest however? Currently away from my machine.

Comment: according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) XMLHttpRequest _can_ return a [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document)-Object. In that case, your `xhr.result` should actually have a `getElementsByClassName` method.

Comment: found it: if you set `xhr.responseType` to `"document"` it should be possible to do this directly. Otherwise: if you have jQuery in your project, you can always just use their selectors instead.

Comment: Selectors are what I would have preferred, but unfortunately cannot use them. If possible can you update your answer? I'll be back tomorrow and see how this method goes!

Comment: @slrpies if this has helped you, you can also "accept" the answer.