# How to render string as HTML through a JS web widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails backend which sends strings like

```
<p>Hello world</p>
```

etc.

But no matter what I do

```
$('div#target').after(...) or $('div#target').html(...)
```

The string remains sanitized. How can I make it into valid HTML?

Note: on my client I only have a `<script>` tag

Code bit that sends the string:

```
function main() {
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var body = "<%= @body %>";
    $('script#parentdiv').after("<div class='parent'></div>");
    $('.parent').html(body);
  });
```

Comment: Can you show the code that sends the string

Comment: You may need to call html_safe on the string getting sent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var body = "<%= @body %>";
```

needs to be

```
var body = "<%= @body.html_safe %>";
```

Answer (score 2):

If you specifically wish to use jQuery then

```
  var str = "hello, <b>my name is</b> jQuery.",
  html = $.parseHTML( str ), 
  // Append the parsed HTML
  $("#anyDomElement").append( html );`
```

This is straight from jQuery docs:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/

Otherwise this can also be done through native easily [Creating a new DOM element from an HTML string using built-in DOM methods or prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143/creating-a-new-dom-element-from-an-html-string-using-built-in-dom-methods-or-pro)

> Any string needs to be parsed and created as nodes of DOM to be understood by browser.