# Javascript get element from text

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have text that contain HTML elements. For example like this

```
<div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>
         <div id="myId">
            <p>
                <span>content</span>
                <span>content</span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </id>   
</div>
```

I want to get `innerHTML` of some element from this text using javascript like this example

```
// HTML variable contain above HTML text
var innerHTML = HTML.getElementById('myId').innerHTML;
```

Is it possible? Or other way like this way?

Comment: http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html - on the last chapter, there's a schema to validate your sitemap

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a new DOM element from an HTML string using built-in DOM methods or prototype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143/creating-a-new-dom-element-from-an-html-string-using-built-in-dom-methods-or-pro)

Comment: Please tell us more about what you're doing - are you doing this in a browser, or with node.js?

Comment: In browser, using javascript.

Comment: What do you want to do? If you want to get the contents of one of those spans, just give it an ID, and then you just do `document.getElementById('itsNewID').innerHTML`

Comment: It isn't in `document`, it is a text in variable.

Comment: Why not include that information in your question? It's unclear to state one thing, but expect another.

Comment: Ok. I edited question and now it is clear.

Comment: To clarify, you mean "get `innerHTML` from an element in an HTML string stored in a variable", correct?  The HTML above is in a variable called `HTML` if I'm understanding this correctly.

Comment: Yes, this is my purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [document fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment).

```js
var HTML = "<div>\
    <div>content</div>\
    <div>\
         <div id=\"myId\">\
            <p>\
                <span>content</span>\
                <span>content</span>\
            </p>\
        </div>\
    </div>\
</div>";

// create a fake document
var df = document.createDocumentFragment();

// create a placeholder node to hold the innerHTML
var el = document.createElement('body');
el.innerHTML = HTML;

// append to the document fragment
df.appendChild(el);

// execute .getElementById
console.log(df.getElementById('myId').innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new element based on your string as described in this question: [Creating a new DOM element from an HTML string using built-in DOM methods or prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/q/494143/936986).

After that you can operate on your new sub-tree with whatever DOM methods you want. You don't need to actually attach it to the page unless you want to use methods that would depend on actual rendering.

```js
var HTML =
'<div>\
    <div>content</div>\
    <div>\
         <div id="myId">\
            <p>\
                <span>content</span>\
                <span>content</span>\
            </p>\
        </div>\
    </id>\
</div>';

var elements = document.createElement('div');
elements.innerHTML = HTML;
var targetElement = elements.querySelectorAll("#myId");

console.log(targetElement)
```

Comment: I create example for your solution but it has problem. See https://jsfiddle.net/0uh9c8kp/

Comment: This is the right idea.  The only problem is that you can't necessarily "operate... with whatever DOM methods you want".  nodes don't have the method `getElementById`.  That is a [method of `document` objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

Comment: @JosephMarikle, well of course you're still bound by usual rules and can only call `Element` methods on element. In this particualr fiddle `var targetElement = elements.querySelectorAll("#myId");` will work.

Comment: How can i get `innerHTML` from `targetElement`?