# How to get the value of image source using typescript?

Tags: html, angularjs, json, typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to access json API and retrieve some data for example : title , category, and images.

The problem is I cant get the source of the images.

I have tried :

- field_image[0].src
- field_image[0].getAttribute('src')
- field_image[0].attr('src')
- etc ..

but nothing worked correctly, it gives me "function not found" or "undefined".

pls help .. and thanks..

this is example of one json object that I retrieved.

```
Object
    body:"this is a normal text"
    field_category:"myCat"
    field_image:Array[2]
    0:
    "<img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://rs.ksu.edu.sa/sites/rs.ksu.edu.sa/files/styles/750x407/public/2017-01-19-photo-00000063.jpg?itok=g4DouHqQ" width="750" height="407" alt="" />"
    1:
    "<img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://rs.ksu.edu.sa/sites/rs.ksu.edu.sa/files/styles/750x407/public/20150817-img_0604.jpg?itok=zNXuoh5t" width="750" height="407" alt="" />"

    length:2
    __proto__:
    Array[0]
    field_issue:"1260"
    field_page_number:"19"
    field_sub_title:"sub"
    field_sub_title1:
    Array[0]
    field_sub_title2:
    Array[0]
    nid:"1269"
    title:"<a href="/issue-1260/1269">this is title</a>"
    __proto__:
```

Comment: field_image elements seems to be raw text strings, not html elements. You can use jQuery.parseHTML() if you're using jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use JQuery:

```
var url = $(field_image[0]).attr('src');
```

This will parse the HTML string for you so you can access the attributes easily.

Comment: or if you do want to use jquery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143/creating-a-new-dom-element-from-an-html-string-using-built-in-dom-methods-or-pro

Comment: @ridwaili, mark the question if this provided the solution.

Comment: It's just a information, because If another user has the same problem as you, he / she will see what worked +1

Answer (score 1):

thanks for [@Andrew Monks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1752741/andrew-monks). He provided me this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143/creating-a-new-dom-element-from-an-html-string-using-built-in-dom-methods-or-pro) where I found the solutin.

**and here is the final solution:**

I declared an attribute:

```
element: HTMLImageElement;
```

then I create this function that take html string and return the img src:

```
getImgSrc(htmlString){
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = htmlString;
    this.element = <HTMLImageElement>div.firstChild;
    return this.element.src;
}
```

and I called it here:

```
{{this.getImgSrc(item.field_image[0])}}
```