# Convert a es6 template string to html element using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

Is there a method to use plain old vanilla javascript (sans frameworks) to convert a html template string into a Html element?

Here's what i've things that i've tried:

```
function renderBody(selector = body, template) {
    const prop.text = 'foobar';
    const templateString = `<div id='test'>${prop.text}</div>`
    const test = document.createElement('div');
    test.innerHTML = templateString;
    document.querySelector(selector).appendChild(test);
}
```

This implementation works but it uses innerHTML and adds an extra wrapped div. There a way to do that without the extra `div`?

Comment: Why don't you just .appendChild(templateString) and remove the 'test' references

Comment: Or just do `const test = document.createElement('div'); test.innerHTML = prop.text;` No string interpolation needed...

Comment: Are you sure that `prop.text` is allowed to contain arbitrary html?

Comment: related - https://stackoverflow.com/q/494143/104380

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML):

```js
function renderBody(selector = 'body', template) {
    const prop = { text: 'foobar' };
    const html = `<div id='test'>${prop.text}</div>`;
    document.querySelector(selector).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
}

renderBody();
```

```css
div { border: 1px solid }
```

```html
<h1>test</h1>
```

I would not call that string variable *templateString* as there is no such thing as a variable that is a template string. Template strings are a literal notation, but when evaluated, they are plain strings. There is nothing in the variable that has some magical trace of "templateness".

Answer (score 15):

I just discovered [`DomParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser). And that's what i was looking for:

```
let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString('<div><b>Hello!</b></div>', 'text/html');
```

Credit: https://davidwalsh.name/convert-html-stings-dom-nodes

Comment: A snippet to get the element: `const domParse = (hmtl) => new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/html").body.firstChild`