# Using Javascript Template Literals With The prepend() Method

Tags: javascript, prepend, template-literals

I have a loop of button elements that are outputted with a `while` loop from data called from a MySQL database via PHP.

A user can add a button to this list and I want to add the new button and it's associated HTML using the `prepend()` method on the parent element, so it appears at the top of the list.

I know how to do this in various stages using createElement and adding class names and attribute names, but wondered if there is a simpler way of doing it using a template literal of the required HTML?

I've seen plenty of examples using parentElement.innerHTML(variableName), where variableName is the template literal, but these button elements illustrated below are inside a loop, and want I to prepend the newly created button to the parent `.board-list` element shown in the HTML.

When a new board name is submitted, a fetch() post request happens in the background to update the database, but I need to create a new element with JavaScript so this shows instantly to the user.

At the moment the template literal `newButton` is added to the HTML inside quote marks as a string of text, not as HTML DOM elements.

**JavaScript**

```
// added into the template literal below
const newBoardName = document.querySelector('.input-title').value;

const newButton = `
<button class="board-list-item full-width" name="board-name" type="submit">
    <span>${newBoardName}</span>
    <span class="add-icon flex">+</span>
</button>
`

document.querySelector(".board-list").prepend(newButton);
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="board-list">

// buttons outputted from the database appear here

</div>

<form>
    <input class="input-title">
    <button name="new-board-name">New Board Name</button>
<form>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a es6 template string to html element using vanilla javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42372432/convert-a-es6-template-string-to-html-element-using-vanilla-javascript)

Comment: strings dont turn automatically into element nodes https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/prepend

Comment: also: [Creating a new DOM element from an HTML string using built-in DOM methods or Prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143/creating-a-new-dom-element-from-an-html-string-using-built-in-dom-methods-or-pro)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution to this was using the `insertAdjacentHTML` method. The question/answer given in one of the comments helped me on this, but I don't think it is a duplicate question, and the question linked to has an overly complicated answer IMHO.

```js
// added into the template literal below
const newBoardName = document.querySelector('.input-title').value

const newButton = `
<button class="board-list-item full-width" name="board-name" type="submit">
    <span>${newBoardName}</span>
    <span class="add-icon flex">+</span>
</button>
`

// insert using 'afterbegin' to add as the first child element
document.querySelector(".board-list").insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', newButton)
```

Comment: It's a duplicate, just close it as such (and the comments link to yet another [Creating a new DOM element from an HTML string using built-in DOM methods or Prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143/creating-a-new-dom-element-from-an-html-string-using-built-in-dom-methods-or-pro))

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple solution is to use `.innerHTML`, here is an example:

```js
// added into the template literal below
const newBoardName = document.querySelector('.input-title').value;

const newButton = `
<button class="board-list-item full-width" name="board-name" type="submit">
    <span>${newBoardName}</span>
    <span class="add-icon flex">+</span>
</button>
`

let boardList = document.querySelector(".board-list");
boardList.innerHTML = newButton + boardList.innerHTML;
```

```html
<div class="board-list">

// buttons outputted from the database appear here

</div>

<form>
    <input class="input-title" value="user1">
    <button name="new-board-name">New Board Name</button>
<form>
```

This is simply to answer your question, although it is not the best solution, so I do not see it recommended.