# Rails 6: form with remote: true and Turbolinks not showing flash after redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, turbolinks, ujs, ruby-on-rails-6

I have `<%= simple_form_for @offer, remote: true %>` with Turbolinks enabled. I'm trying to redirect and show success flash with something like this in my `update` action:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @offer.update(offer_params)
    flash[:success] = "#{@offer.name} #{t(:updated)}"
    format.html { redirect_to seller_offers_path }
    format.js
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
  end
end
```

My `update.js.erb` has code not related to redirect or flash:

```
$(".ibox-content.actions").removeClass('sk-loading');
$('.sk-spinner').css("display", "none");
```

In application.html.erb I can render flash with this:

```
<div class="row">
  <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
     <%= content_tag(:div, content_tag(:strong, message), id: "flash_message",
                   class: "text-bold alert alert-#{message_type}") %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

At the moment my form is saved, however no redirect.

When I add `Turbolinks.visit(<%= seller_offers_path %>)` in `update.js.erb` form is saved, redirect is done, however there is no flash.

**Is there a way I can have flash shown on redirected page with Turbolinks and `remote: true` , please?** So far I've tried [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43418407), however it works only for showing flash on same page - it doesn't work with `redirect_to`.

**Update**

This does redirect, however no flash:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @offer.update(offer_params)
    format.js { redirect_to seller_offers_path, success: "#{@offer.name} #{t(:updated)}" }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
  end
end
```

**Update 2**

At the moment I'm trying to implement something like
`Turbolinks.visit(url, { keep: 'flash' });` as [mentioned in docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/turbolinks), however doesn't seem to be working with Turbolinks 5.2

**Update 3**

I've removerd `update.js.erb` and in my controller I have

```
def update
  if @offer.update(offer_params)
    flash[:success] = "#{@offer.name} #{t(:updated)}"
    redirect_to seller_offers_path
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

Redirect is done as expected, however still no flash displayed on `index`. I can print my flash at the end of `update` action:

`#<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash:0x00007f180d2a1c60 @discard=#<Set: {}>, @flashes={"success"=>"My offer updated!"}, @now=nil>`

however at the end of `index` action (where I redirect_to) it is empty:

`#<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash:0x00007f180eb3b780 @discard=#<Set: {}>, @flashes={}, @now=nil>`

Looks like my flash is not kept for next request. Is it because of Turbolinks, or other some reason? I'd be happy for any hint.

Comment: If you are going to redirect, why do you need the form to be submitted with remote: true?

Comment: @Tashows I don't want my page to do full refresh - Turbolinks can replace my view with something from `index` action for example.

Comment: Hey @matiss, maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23967390/rails-flash-notice-via-ajax

Comment: @Violeta Thank you, I have solution in place for AJAX without redirect, however I'm looking for solution for `Turbolinks.visit` - please, see my update 2 above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Redirecting after remote form submissions

When you use forms that submit via JS (e.g. `remote: true` or the default `form_with`), Rails will lookup and render the conventional `js` response (in this case `offers/update.js.erb`) and ignore any others, such as the `html` redirect.

Your original `update.js.erb` did not include any code to perform the visit to the redirect location, and so it only removed the class name and hid the spinner.

As you've figured out, the `js` response needs to make a Turbolinks `visit` to the redirect location. It's also a good idea to clear the Turbolinks cache after a form submission, so your `update.js.erb` might look something like:

```
$(".ibox-content.actions").removeClass('sk-loading');
$('.sk-spinner').css("display", "none");
Turbolinks.clearCache();
Turbolinks.visit(<%= seller_offers_path %>);
```

If you have the turbolinks-rails gem installed, and do not need to run any custom JS, like the first two lines above, then in your controller you can simply do:

```
def update
  if @offer.update(offer_params)
    flash[:success] = "#{@offer.name} #{t(:updated)}"
    redirect_to seller_offers_path
  else
    render :edit # see note below*
  end
```

You won't need `update.js.erb`; turbolinks-rails will automatically clear the cache and visit the redirect path. This is nice as it keeps your controller code tidy (no need for `respond_to`), and works for both HTML and JS requests.

* It's worth noting that error responses from JS requests will still need to be handled manually. To do this, you may find this comment useful: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/issues/85#issuecomment-338784510

### Missing Flash

I think the reason why your flash isn't showing in your updated code is because you are using the shorthand style of setting flash messages in `redirect_to, which only supports`notice`and`alert`:

```
redirect_to seller_offers_path, notice: '…' # sets flash[:notice]
redirect_to seller_offers_path, alert: '…' # sets flash[:slert]
redirect_to seller_offers_path, success: '…' # doesn't work
```

If you wish to use your own flash key you'll need to set the flash explicitly:

```
flash[:success] = "#{@offer.name} #{t(:updated)}"
```

---

I should also add that the Turbolinks `keep` option is not supported in Turbolinks 5. I think it was a feature in Turbolinks 2 or 3. The [Turbolinks README](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks) is the place for the most up-to-date docs.

I hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you, however still no flash on my redirected_to page. Can you take a look on my Update 3 above, please?

Comment: I found my problem - there was conflic with some other JS and one module I had in `lib`. I removed unnecessary files and now my flash works just fine.

Comment: Can you explain your conflict? I'm having the same problem.