# Get href link from a string Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a string

```
<a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a> This is a good page
```

I try to get only http://google.com but i can't.

Please give me some solution to do it, thank you.

Comment: you mean you want value of href attribute?

Comment: you want to get it from where, `href` or inside the `<a></a>`?

Comment: Get google.com between <a></a>

Comment: I have two questions. First, You say this is a string, but I'm not sure that's what you really mean. Are you running jQuery on a normal webpage, and is this text in the webpage? (If so, this is the DOM, not a regular string.) Second, do you want to keep the text "This is a good page" in your output?

Comment: 1. I' running Jquery on my page, i get this text from Json, it is a string from json.
2. Yes, i want to keep this text.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try following js code,

following code is working but not recommended,

```
$('a').attr('href');


$("a").attr('href','javascript:void(0)');

Get the text :

$("a").text()
```

Comment: Welcome, @thanhhuy12thh

Comment: Depending on where the JSON data comes from, and how you intend to use the string, this answer could be dangerous. It might lead to a [cross-site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) vulnerability. Instead, you should parse the HTML with a proper HTML parser, or if you can change the code that is generating the JSON, adjust the JSON format so that you don't have to parse any HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you want the jQuery version:

```
let string = $('a').attr('href');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**Get the value :**

```
$('a').attr('href');
```

**Replace the link :**

```
$("a").attr('href','javascript:void(0)');
```

**Get the text :**

```
$("a").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to convert the string to DOM elements, using one of the techniques in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143/creating-a-new-dom-element-from-an-html-string-using-built-in-dom-methods-or-pro). (I use the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143/creating-a-new-dom-element-from-an-html-string-using-built-in-dom-methods-or-pro/494348#494348), but you should choose the one that matches your use-case the best.)

```
var str = '<a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a> This is a good page';
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = str;
```

You can then manipulate the elements using normal JavaScript DOM methods. Here I do it with jQuery:

```
$(div).text(); // "http://google.com This is a good page"
$('a', div).attr('href'); // "http://google.com"
```

A final note: beware when working with with HTML strings! If you put untrusted HTML into your page's DOM, you will create a [cross-site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) vulnerability. If you control the source of the JSON data, then it would be a good idea to just send the strings you need, instead of HTML strings - that way you can avoid parsing the HTML altogether.