# Getting via AJAX an HTML that uses WebComponents

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, polymer, web-component

I have a page made with WebComponents standard (mainly paper elements by Polymer) and I need get via AJAX an portion of HTML page.

When I append the HTML getted via AJAX to my page, don't render correctly.

[image: How render HTML]

In the image, can be apreciate, the `paper-card heading="Dominio .com"` is a `paper-card` that the HTML is getted via AJAX and appended to the page, but isn't getting the attributes that Polymer sets automatically and in page, the paper card isn't rendered correctly.

[image: How render WebView]

I transform the HTML getted via AJAX with [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35385518/4667174).

Comment: due to security reasons it is not possible to insert custom elements getted from ajax. The link you provided has some workarounds but it's still bad approach :/ i tried to find relevant articles on stackoverflow or github, but unfrotunately i can't find any

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that - use `importHref`.

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Base#method-importHref

It will dynamicaly fetch and register an element for you.