# Parsing HTML String into DOM

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, npm, request

In this project I'm working on, I'm using the npm package 'request' and have a code which looks something like this

```
request({
  url: 'https://www.google.com/'
}, (error, response, body) => {
  // does stuff here
});
```

Now, request returns a body which is basically a long string of HTML elements which looks like

```
<!doctype html><html> ... </html>
```

What I need to do is convert that string into a DOM so that I can use methods such as `getElementById()` or `getElementByClassName()` so I can return whatever values those elements contain.

I know there are libraries such as cheerio which does exactly what I need, but as of this moment I can't use those packages yet so I need to try and find a way to implement this with vanilla javascript.

Comment: you want the entire string to be inserted as HTML into a DOM element?

Comment: I just want to transform it into an element so I can use functions like getElementById() so I can return their values.  This is all happening in the server code, so I wouldn't need to display the HTML anyway.

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143/creating-a-new-dom-element-from-an-html-string-using-built-in-dom-methods-or-pro)
have a look at this. Use regex to extract parts of the HTML

Comment: Why can't you use cheerio? Have you tried jsdom? @AbdulSamad That's an awful idea. Might I remind you of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: @AbdulSamad thanks, I'll check that out now.

Comment: @Ben and why is that so?He explicitly mentions that he wants to use Vanilla JS

Comment: @BenFortune Adding new node packages to our project requires asking for permission from our managers and leads, which I've already done. My lead just asked me to try and implement this in vanilla javascript in the meantime, in case permission is denied.

Comment: @AbdulSamad The DOM API's do not exist in node, it is not a browser.

Comment: Obviously, they don't. He will have to send the data over an API to the browser and the element creation will be done on client side.