# How to get value in react-widgets DropdownList when select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am practicing `frontend` skill please advice

The solution in my head is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143/creating-a-new-dom-element-from-an-html-string-using-built-in-dom-methods-or-pro). I have to debark the tab by myself
When I look into the [official doc](https://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/api/DropdownList/#onSelect). I has a listener function implemented, but it will hand on the value when you click `submit` button.

I want to `dispatch` the selected value immediately in the app.
What is the best practice on this?

`onSelect` is fine. I can see the `selectedValue`, but it is not exact result I want. I want it from `onChange`.

```
let ReactWidgetsForm = props => {
  const {handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting, variants, colors} = props;
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <Field
          name="variantName"
          component={DropdownList}
          data={colors}
          valueField="value"
          textField="color"
          onSelect={(event)=>{
            console.log(event);
          }}
          onClick={(event) =>{
            console.log(event.target);
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </form>
  )
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are many things wrong in my code!
I have to use `stateful class-based component` not just plain `function-based component`

```
class VariantDropdownList extends Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.state = { value: '--' };
    this.colors = [{color: 'Red', value: 'ff0000'},
      {color: 'Green', value: '00ff00'},
      {color: 'Orange', value: '#FF4500'},
      {color: 'Blue', value: '0000ff'}];
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <DropdownList
          data={this.colors}
          value={this.state.value}
          valueField='color'
          textField='color'
          onChange={(value) => {
              console.log(value);
              this.setState({ value })
            }
          }
        />
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```