# Parsing And Accessing Dom Elements From HTML Page Fetched Via Ajax XHR Get Request

Tags: javascript, dom, xmlhttprequest, html-parsing

We are trying a access various DOM elements from full HTML pages that are remotely fetched via XHR GET request.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://www.example.com/test.html", true);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    var newdom = xhr.responseText;
    var val_result = newdom.a_div.innerText;
    // we want to access the text within this div, from the fetched html page?
  }
}

xhr.send();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is a string newdom? Is a string dom?

Comment: If newdom is a dom string pleade read answers to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143/creating-a-new-dom-element-from-an-html-string-using-built-in-dom-methods-or-pro

Answer (score 4):

Easily enough you could do this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open('GET', 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53661013/parsing-and-accessing-dom-elements-from-html-page-fetched-via-ajax-xhr-get-reque/53661204', true)

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    var dom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xhr.responseText, 'text/html')
    console.log(dom.querySelector('#question-header h1').innerText)
  }
}

xhr.send()
```

If you copy this code as-is in your browser console, it will print the title of your StackOverflow question! Simply use the `dom` variable to query for the element you are looking for in.

Comment: Thats great apercu, I am trying to use DOMparser with getElementById() and getElementsByClassName() instead of queryselector() ?

Comment: Same thing, use `dom.getElementById` or `dom.getElementsByClassName` :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an element with

```
const el=document.createElement('div')
```

then assign its innerhtml

```
el.innerHTML = newdom
```

Then you should be able to access the nodes