# Displaying a font-awesome spinner on sweet alert dialog box

Tags: font-awesome, sweetalert

Am working on an application whereby I have a sweet alert dialog box to display to a user when h/she clicks on Payment button, I want to display a font-awesome spinner on the sweet alert dialog box besides the text property but it shows the font-awesome code instead on the loading spinner:

**Sweet alert code**

```
  swal({
        title: "Message Sent",
        icon: '{{ asset('assets/images/mpesa.png')}}',
        imageWidth: 30,
        imageHeight: 30,
        imageAlt: 'Mpesa Icon',
        text: "Please Check your Phone for a payment dialogue" + '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>',
        closeOnClickOutside: false,
        buttons:false
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `content` option instead of `text` and set it to some DOM node as described in the [documentation](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#using-dom-nodes-as-content). Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/494143/170403) on how to create a DOM node from HTML string.

Comment: Thanks,, I need the icon to appear beside the text