# Find certain data in string with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, parsing

I have a string in JavaScript application:

```
const articleBody = "<div class=\"article\" data-id=\"123456\" data-title=\"Some long article title\">Article content goes here.</div>"
```

There is no way for me to set this as HTML and then get data- values as I would normally do, so I need to "extract" data- attribute values from string. In the end I need to have something like that:

```
const id="123456"
const title="Some long article title"
```

How would I do that with JavaScript?

Thank you!

Comment: "There is no way for me to set this as HTML and then get data- values as I would normally do" Why not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a new DOM element from an HTML string using built-in DOM methods or Prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143/creating-a-new-dom-element-from-an-html-string-using-built-in-dom-methods-or-pro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take up the string and try converting it into HTML template using `document.createElement`..

```
const template = document.createElement('div');
template.innerHTML = articleBody;
```

Then you can use `getAttribute` method to retrieve the value of the `attribute` you wish to fetch..

```
const id = template.querySelector('.article').getAttribute("data-id");
const title = template.querySelector('.article').getAttribute("data-title");
```

And the expected solution can be formed as,

```js
const articleBody = "<div class=\"article\" data-id=\"123456\" data-title=\"Some long article title\">Article content goes here.</div>"


const template = document.createElement('div');
template.innerHTML = articleBody;

const id = template.querySelector('.article').getAttribute("data-id");
const title = template.querySelector('.article').getAttribute("data-title");

console.log(id, title);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`template`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template).

```js
const articleBody = "<div class=\"article\" data-id=\"123456\" data-title=\"Some long article title\">Article content goes here.</div>"

const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = articleBody;
const article = template.content.children[0];

const {
  id,
  title
} = article.dataset;

console.log(id, title);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use this script here, it will split your string to array, get the attribute, get numbers from it with regex and parse it to int:

```
var str = "<div class=\"article\" data-id=\"1234576\" data-title=\"Some long article title\">Article content goes here.</div>";
var attribute = str.split(" ").filter(item =>{
  return item.includes("data-id");
});
var result = attribute.toString().replace( /^\D+/g, '').match(/\d+/)[0];
console.log(parseInt(result));
```