# Losing Event Listeners on Function Recall

Tags: javascript, dom-events

UPDATE: Here's a shorter and a simpler snippet to demonstrate my problem. Try to click on the first button and its corresponding event listener does not work. Only the second one.

```js
var a = {};
a.b = 0;
a.alert = () => {
 a.b++;
 document.getElementById('X').innerHTML += '<button id="_'+a.b+'">Button #'+a.b+'</button>';
 document.getElementById('_'+a.b).addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
  var p = document.getElementById('_'+a.b);
  p.parentElement.removeChild(p);
 });
}


a.alert();
a.alert();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<span id="X"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE: It seems that I really lose the event. I checked DevTools and the created elements prior to that lose the click event when I execute the function again.

I would like to ask for some help with trying to tame event listeners. It seems that if I try to call the function multiple times, only the last function seems to work, which is a problem since I would like to have the ability to show multiple alerts. Here's what I'm trying to do.

Is there something that I'm missing here? Or is this a problem with using objects to contain functions?

```js
var alertify = {}
alertify.depth = [];
alertify.alert = (title, text, callback = () => {}) => {
 var uniq = 'uniqalert_'+uniqid();
 alertify.depth.push(uniq);
 var content =
 '<form onsubmit="return false" class="dialog" id="'+uniq+'">\
  <div class="box">\
   <div class="box_title">\
    <div class="box_title_content">'+title+'</div>\
    <img id="i'+uniq+'" src="'+operator.config.ximage+'">\
   </div>\
   <div class="box_content">'+text+'</div>\
   <div class="box_button">\
    <button class="yes" id="j'+uniq+'">OK</button>\
   </div>\
  </div>\
 </form>';
 selector('alertcontainer').innerHTML += content;
 var f = selector(uniq);
 selector('i'+uniq).addEventListener('click',()=>{
  callback();
  f.parentNode.removeChild(f);
 });
 selector('j'+uniq).addEventListener('click',()=>{
  callback();
  f.parentNode.removeChild(f);
 });
}
```

Note: I am not affiliated to the alertify/js team. I just used that var name as I'm accustomed to using it before.

Comment: what is the content of the `uniqid()` method? and is `selector` meant to be `document.querySelector`?

Comment: ``uniqid()`` returns a number that just increments up every time I call it, and yes. That's just a query selector, specifically ``getElementById``. I made it into a short function to avoid typing it longer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that appending the HTML string, giving it an ID, and fetching that ID is a bad way of doing it. I have found this snippet that converts the string to a valid [HTML DOM element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143/creating-a-new-dom-element-from-an-html-string-using-built-in-dom-methods-or-pro) is better. Not sure though why the old code does not work as logically it should. It would be good if someone can enlighten me on why the old code is wrong.

```js
function createElementFromHTML(htmlString) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = htmlString.trim();
  // Change this to div.childNodes to support multiple top-level nodes
  return div.firstChild; 
}

var a = {};
a.b = 0;
a.alert = () => {
 a.b++;

 var c = createElementFromHTML('<button id="_'+a.b+'">Button #'+a.b+'</button>');
 document.getElementById('X').appendChild(c);

 c.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
  c.parentElement.removeChild(c);
 });
}

a.alert();
a.alert();
a.alert();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<span id="X"></span>
</body>
</html>
```