# Fetched data duplicates itself after sorting

Tags: javascript, html

I fetched data by using fetch api into a table. I sort my data by clicking on column headers. It works but after it's sorted,it duplicates data. I checked on it,but i guess there's someting i've missed.

```js
let data =[];
function veriAl() 
{
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
   .then(response =>{
   if(!response.ok)
     {
       throw Error("ERROR");
     }
   return response.json();
   })
    .then(veri => {
    data=veri;
   veriEkle(data);
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}

const sort_data = (field) =>
{
  data.sort((a,b) => {
    let valueA=a[field];
    let valueB= b[field];
    if(valueA<valueB)
      {
        return -1;
      }
    else if(valueB>valueA)
      {
        return 1;
      }
    return 0;            
  })
  console.log("sıralandı"+field+"e göre",data);
  veriEkle(data);
  }
const veriEkle =(array)=>
{
  
  const html=array.map(user =>{
    return `<table class="user">
      <td> ${user.id}</td>
      <td>${user.name}</td>
      <td>${user.username}</td>
      <td>${user.email}</td>
    <td>${user.address.street}/${user.address.suite}/${user.address.city}</td>
      </table>
     `;
    
  }).join("");
   console.log(html); document.querySelector('#veri_tablo').insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin",html);
}
veriAl();
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
<table class="table" id="veri_tablo">
 <thead class="thead-dark">
   <tr>
     <th onclick="sort_data('id')">ID</th>
     <th onclick="sort_data('name')">Name</th>
     <th onclick="sort_data('username')">Username</th>
     <th onclick="sort_data('email')">Email</th>
     <th onclick="sort_data('address')">Adres</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
</table>
<div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `sort` doesn't remove duplicates, you need to `filter` the duplicates.

Comment: If you console log the data before sorting, and after sorting in `sort_data()`, is the data right before sorting? Is it duplicated after sorting?

Comment: From what I've seen, there are no duplicates here. Results may have the same names but different other data such as email and username
Secondly, `sort` modifies an array in place. In other words, it modifies the original array (which is usually not what you want). I think you should destructure the array before sorting: `[...data].sort(...)`

Answer (score 0):

```
 console.log("sıralandı"+field+"e göre",data);
  veriEkle(data); //---->Here
```

You should maybe edit here like `veriEkle(...data);` or you should use filter function instead of "sort"

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be nothing wrong with your data. It's not being duplicated. It is the html that's being duplicated. You're appending html without removing the existing entries. You should have a container element and change the inner html of that container instead.

Your js should look something like this...

```js
//...
const veriEkle = (array) => {
  const html = array.map(user => {
    return `<tr class="user">
          <td> ${user.id}</td>
          <td>${user.name}</td>
          <td>${user.username}</td>
          <td>${user.email}</td><td>${user.address.street}/${user.address.suite}/${user.address.city}</td>
          </tr>
         `;
  }).join("");
  console.log(html);
  document.getElementById('table_content').innerHTML = html;
}
```

And your html

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <table class="table" id="veri_tablo">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th onclick="sort_data('id')">
            ID
          </th>
          <th onclick="sort_data('name')">
            Name
          </th>
          <th onclick="sort_data('username')">
            Username
          </th>
          <th onclick="sort_data('email')">
            Email
          </th>
          <th onclick="sort_data('address')">
            Adress
          </th>
        </tr>

        <tbody id="table_content" /> //the container element
      </thead>
    </table>
    <div />
  </div>
</div>
```

**PS** Using the `innerHTML` property is not considered best practice and you should look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143/creating-a-new-dom-element-from-an-html-string-using-built-in-dom-methods-or-pro) for the best ways to create and render elements from html strings.