# Why does the DIV thinks the Element is a string?

Tags: javascript, html

I try to append a button on a div element, that isn't defined in the html page.

This is my Function to create the Button:

```
const img2dView = function (name) {
      return `<button class="gridButton">
            <img alt = ${name} src="$...images/${name}.png" style="width: 100%;">
          </button>`;
    };
```

if i append this on an already defined div it works:

```
$someDiv.append(img2dView(SomeName));
```

but if i try this on a new created div, the button is just a string:

```
let helpDiv = document.createElement('div');
      helpDiv.class = 'square';
      helpDiv.append(img2dView(SomeNames[i]));
```

Output:

```
<div>
     "<button class="gridButton">
            <img alt = blocked src="assets/.....png" style="width: 100%;">
          </button>;"
</div>
```

**I think i need .appendChild. But then I get a error Message, that "img2dView(SomeNames[i])" isn't a node**

Comment: Is `$someDiv` a jQuery object? There is no `.append()` method on ordinary DOM nodes.

Comment: hmh i dont know actually, but on $someDiv the .append is working :D

Comment: Well where does `$someDiv` get its value?

Comment: @Pointy Yes there is, and that's what's causing confusion here. `jQueryObject.append()` will interpret the string as HTML and parse it, whereas `ParentNode.append()` takes strings literally.

Comment: oh ok, yes it's a jquery object. I define it in the index file. And then
export const  $someDiv= $('#SomeDiv');

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol ok thanks! but how can i append the button on a ParentNode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with:

```
const img2dView = function (name) {
      let div = document.createElement('div');
      div.innerHTML =`<button class="gridButton">
            <img alt = ${name} src="...${name}.png" style="width: 100%;">
          </button>`;
      return div.firstChild;
    };
```

thanks to:
[Creating a new DOM element from an HTML string using built-in DOM methods or Prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143/creating-a-new-dom-element-from-an-html-string-using-built-in-dom-methods-or-pro)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery use as:

```
$someDiv = $('<div />');
$someDiv.append('<button class="gridButton"> <img alt = blocked src="assets/.....png" style="width: 100%;"> </button>');
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I don't want to use jQuery there :)