# Getting ElementID from Fetch?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api

I'm trying to do a fetch request to example.com, and trying to get a specific ElementID from the fetched  webpage into the console log without success.

I've tried the following code without success yet:

```
const url = "https://example.com"; 
fetch(url) 
  .then(response => response)
  .then(data => {
    const resData = data.text();
    console.log(resData);
    document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = resData;
  })
.catch((err) => console.log("Can’t access " + url + " response. Blocked by browser?" + err));
```

I'll be for your suggestions'. Thanks

I'm getting TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: `.then(response => response)` does nothing ... you need to return `response.text()` - since, `const resData = data.text();` results in `resData` being a Promise ... i.e. `fetch(url).then(response => response.text()).then(resData => {`

Comment: copy your html and the response you are getting from url.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that your current document
does not contain an element wit the id "id" (`document.getElementById("id")`).
This results that this expression will evaluate to `null` which explains the error you're facing.

In your case I would suggest something like this:
Creating a new container where you can insert the HTML code and work with.
As reference:  [Creating a new DOM element from an HTML string using built-in DOM methods or Prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143/creating-a-new-dom-element-from-an-html-string-using-built-in-dom-methods-or-pro)

```js
const url = "https://example.com"; 
fetch(url) 
  .then(data => {
    const resData = data.text();
    console.log(resData);

    const responseContainer = document.createElement("div");
    responseContainer.innerHTML = "";

    /* 
     * Work with the responseContainer.
     * As example to get all elements with class "example":
     * responseContainer.getElementsByClassName("example")
     */
  })
.catch((err) => console.log("Can’t access " + url + " response. Blocked by browser?" + err));
```

Answer (score 0):

An error you're getting simply shows that there is not such element on the page you're trying to fetch.

If you want to do that, make sure there is a div with that id and if it's not there make sure you make it before you send response.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).