# Creating multiple HTML elements with JavaScript. Dynamic forms?

Tags: javascript, forms

I'd like to insert a block of HTML into the DOM when a checkbox or radio button or button is pressed.
For example, when a button is pressed, then another set of the `labels` and `inputs` below are added to the form.

```
<form class="details">
<div>
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">

  <label for="job">Job:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="job" name="job"><br>
  <label for="id">ID:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="id" name="id">

  <label for="shoesize">Shoe size:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="shoesize" name="shoesize"><br>
  <label for="helmetsize">Helmet size:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="helmetsize" name="helmetsize">
</div>
</form>
```

Every time a button is pressed I'd like another set of fields where someone else can add their details to the form.

I am aware of `document.createElement()`, but it seems like I can only create 1 element at a time using that. This form will probably grow and so would like something less verbose.

I've experimented with `appendChild()`  e.g.

```js
var details = document.getElementsByClassName('details')[0]

var newDetailsSection = '<div>
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">

  <label for="job">Job:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="job" name="job"><br>
  <label for="id">ID:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="id" name="id">

  <label for="shoesize">Shoe size:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="shoesize" name="shoesize"><br>
  <label for="helmetsize">Helmet size:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="helmetsize" name="helmetsize">
</div>'

details.appendChild(newDetailsSection)
```

But I am getting an error because `newDetailsSection` is not of type `Node` - it is a string and I understand that.

I am new to web development.

Is this a use case for a JS framework that handles components? Is this what a component is?

Comment: for this case try `details.innerHTML = newDetailsSection;`

Comment: That is replacing the current HTML with the HTML in `newDetailsSection`, I'd like to append more questions to the form.

Comment: if you want to append html to the innerHtml of an element you can use the += operator... like details.innerHTML += newDetailsSection; Otherwise you could rely on JQuery that let's you create entire html nodes from html string or rely on vanilla js suggestions like given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143/creating-a-new-dom-element-from-an-html-string-using-built-in-dom-methods-or-pro

Comment: I'm not using `innerHTML` method because [it disrupts `eventListeners`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML). After HTML is inserted, none of the `eventListeners` work.   then tried `insertAdjacentHTML` because this doesn't disrupt `eventListeners`, but the new elements inserted don't seem to work with the existing `eventListeners`. Now trying DOM functions..

Answer (score 1):

if u want to add html string; innerHTML is your friend.

to append use `details.innerHtML = details.innerHtML + newSectionHTML`;

ofcourse i would recommend using `document.createElement` and create a function that returns element that contain label:

example:

```
function creatInput(name, label){
const labelElm = document.createElement('label');
const inputElm = document.createElement('input');

labelElm.setAttribute('for', name);
labelElm.innerText = label+':';

inputElm.setAttribute('name', name);
inputElm.setAttribute('id', name);
inputElm.setAttribute('placeholder', label);

labelElm.appendChild(input);

return labelElm;
}
```

this way you can reuse it for all your input simply call:

```
var details = document.querySelector(".details");

details.appendChild( createInput('fname','First name') );
details.appendChild( createInput('lname','Last name') );
/// .. etc
```

Comment: In `createInput()` there is a parameter with the same name as a variable - 'label'.

Comment: @AmbassadorKosh nice catch :) i fixed it, sorry I typed code directly in sof ^.^