# Javascript fetch to filter by ID of fetched content

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am using JavaScript to fetch a document via ajax, but what I would like to do is filter the retrieved content by ID, in this example "#container".

In jQuery it can be done like this:

```
lightbox.load( "test.html #container" );
```

My JavaScript looks like this:

```
let response = fetch("test.html").then(function(response) {
    if (response.ok) {
        response.text().then(function(text) {
            lightbox.innerHTML = text;
        });
    }
});
```

The above is putting the entire text response into the lightbox object. I am not sure how to filter the response by the #container ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **create a new HTML element from the receiving HTML** and then **search for your container**.

```
let response = fetch("test.html").then(function(response) {
    if (response.ok) {
        response.text().then(function(text) {
            const template = document.createElement('template');
            template.innerHTML = text;
            const lightBoxContent = template.content.querySelector('#container');
            lightbox.innerHTML = lightBoxContent.innerHTML;
        });
    }
});
```

Inspiration by: [Creating a new DOM element from an HTML string using built-in DOM methods or Prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143/creating-a-new-dom-element-from-an-html-string-using-built-in-dom-methods-or-pro/35385518#35385518)