# How do I initialize a whole div from LocalStorage in HTML without breaking it with "/"?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, local-storage

So, I am creating a "favorites page" using local storage to store the items that you click to add to favorites, the items are normal cards like this (just an example):

```
<div class="card__box"> 
            <div class="heart-wrapper"><a href="#" class="fas fa-heart" id="auditoria"></a></div>
            <div onclick="link('index.html?BI=auditoria')">
                <div class="card__icon"><img src="./assets/icons/auditoria.png"></div>
                <div class="icon__text">
                    <span class="icon__header"><strong>Auditoria</strong></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I am saving them in local storage with outer.HTML
[(how localStorage is saving them)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCka5.png)

the thing is, when I try to show them in the HTML the LocalStorage give the value with some alterations like bars "/" and "\n". (like this):
"<div class="card_mini_box"> \n            <div class="times-mini-wrapper"><a href="#" class="fas fa-times" id="auditoria" aria-hidden="true">\n            <div onclick="link('index.html?BI=auditoria')">\n                <div class="card_mini_icon"><img src="./assets/icons/auditoria.png">\n                <div class="icon_mini_text">\n                    <span class="icon_mini_header">**Auditoria**\n                \n            \n        "

As u can see all messed up.

I am saving them in localstorage like this:

```
let favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites')) || []
```

```
        const source = favdiv.outerHTML;
        
        favorites.push(source);
        localStorage.setItem('favorites', JSON.stringify(favorites));
```

(favdiv is the whole div selected)

And I am trying to show them in HTML like this:

```
    var output = document.getElementById("mini__cards");
    var element = document.createElement("div");
    element.textContent = localStorage.getItem('favorites');
    output.appendChild(element);
```

please help me I tried a lot of different methods and none of them worked.

Already Tried saving with innerHTML and also tried to put them in html with innerHTML as well.

Comment: You forgot to (a) Deal with the array and (b) Parse the JSON

Answer (score 0):

for this method to work, some details were missing when saving and showing the favorites.

When getting the div, use `innerHTML`, it gets the elements inside the selected div, so there is no risk of duplicating IDs.
Before saving, removing breaking lines.
When showing data, remember to use a loop to show all stored data.

Your code would look like this to save:

```
var favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("favorites")) || [];

var favdiv = 
document.getElementById("divs").innerHTML.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\s\s)/gm, "");
favorites.push(favdiv);

localStorage.setItem("favorites", JSON.stringify(favorites));
```

Using replace, I remove line breaks, with `\n` and `\r`.

And to view the saved divs, I use a `forEach` to go through the entire array, create a `template` and show its `content` as the last element:

```
var favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("favorites"));
var output = document.getElementById("mini__cards");

favorites.forEach((favorite) => {
  let tempElement = document.createElement("template");
  tempElement.innerHTML = favorite.trim();
  output.append(tempElement.content);
});
```

More detailed explanation about above code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35385518/20815693

This is the result for your case, using jquery this code can be reduced and easier to handle DOM. I hope I have helped you.