# Parse html fragment that contains a table row

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have the following response returned from a server. It's a html fragment.
I want to parse it with DOMParser like this:

```
let responseText = '<div>Text Content</div><tr><td>Cell</td></tr>';
let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(`<body><template>${responseText}</template></body>`, 'text/html');
let fragment = doc.body.firstChild.content;
```

Here the `fragment` variable in runtime contains the following DOM:

```
#document-fragment
  <div>Text Content</div>
  Cell
```

**My question:** I expected it to contain `<tr>` but it doesn't. How do I change the parsing code so that it properly contains  element?

I'm not allowed to change response text.

Comment: `<tr>` is only a valid child of `<table>`, `<thead>` or `<tbody>`.

Comment: *"I'm not allowed to change response text."* - Then what you have is a malformed HTML structure, which likely would require parsing it manually instead of using a DOM parser (which would attempt to "correct" the structure just like a browser does).

Answer (score 1):

The `<tr>` element is only a valid child of `<table>`, `<thead>`,  `<tbody>` or `<tfoot>`. See excerpt from MDN below for more informaition.

Try wrapping the `<tr>` in a `<table>` and using `createContextualFragment` instead.

```js
let responseText = '<div>Text Content</div><tr><td>Cell</td></tr>';
responseText = responseText
  .replace(/<tr>/, '<table>$0')
  .replace(/<\/tr>/, '$0</table>');

const fragment = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(responseText);
const cellContent = fragment.querySelector('td').innerText;

console.log(cellContent); // Cell
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

See:

> ##### [MDN ~ `<tr>`: The Table Row element ~ Technial summary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr#technical_summary)
>
> **Permitted parents** `<table>` (only if the table has no child `<tbody>` element, and even then only after any `<caption>`, `<colgroup>`, and `<thead>` elements); otherwise, the parent must be `<thead>`, `<tbody>` or `<tfoot>`

Answer (score 0):

DomParser is quite strict when parsing HTML. The HTML example you provided is not in accordance with the specification

Here are rules to be followed.
[HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing-main-inhtml)

According to that document, you should not put `<div>` next to `<tr>`

This answer should also help
[Create new DOM element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143/creating-a-new-dom-element-from-an-html-string-using-built-in-dom-methods-or-pro)