# Thead parsing returns null

Tags: javascript, parsing, html-table

I have the following function:

```
function parseMarkupToDOM(markup) {
    return new DOMParser().parseFromString(markup, "text/html").body.firstElementChild;
}
```

When passing most elements, it works just fine. For instance:

```
parseMarkupToDOM(`<button>myButton</button>`); // returns a proper DOM element
parseMarkupToDOM(`<h1>myHeading</h1>`); // returns a proper DOM element
```

However, when I try to parse a `thead` into a DOM element, I get `null`:

```
parseMarkupToDOM(`
    <thead>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
    </thead>
`); // returns null
```

I thought that maybe `thead` cannot be the child of `body`, but I am not sure how to get around it, and was not able to find any useful information about this issue. Any idea?

Comment: That's invalid HTML, `<thead>` can only be used inside `<table>`.

Comment: Because that's invalid HTML. It needs to be in a `table`. Some browsers will enter quirks mode and try to fix it by automatically adding a table in the DOM for you but regular HTML parsers normally won't do that.

Comment: @Barmar So how would you do that? How to change the function so it could parse all HTML elements?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75652465/parse-html-fragment-that-contains-a-table-row

Comment: @Barmar - well, I read the answers there and they focus on a solution specifically for `tr` -- namely, they suggest wrapping it with a table. This is not quite what I am looking for. I need a function that can parse *any* HTML, and wrapping a `button` with a `table` will be meaningless.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a general purpose solution. DOMParser requires the HTML to be valid. If it's not, you have to wrap it in whatever it takes to make it valid.

Comment: This may be an XY problem. What are you doing that requires parsing arbitrary fragments of HTML?

Comment: @Barmar - Maybe... I am creating some [custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_custom_elements), but it is extremely exhausting to build their inner HTML using DOM functions. Parsing HTML will be much easier.